# How to keep /*! comments with UglifyJS2?

Tags: node.js, uglifyjs2

The default behaviour looks for `@license` or `@preserve`...

But many plugins and libraries are still using `/*!` for licensing comment blocks...

How can I use [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#usage) to preserve comments starting with `/*!` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#usage

Using the `--comments` argument, you can supply a regular expression.

```
uglifyjs jquery.plugin.js --comments '/^\/*!/' -o outfile.js
```

Comment: For me I had to do it without the quotes around the expression, eg. uglifyjs jquery.plugin.js --comments /^\/*!/ -o outfile.js

Answer (score 1):

In case that you use this VSCode extension 
[JS & CSS Minifier (Minify)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=olback.es6-css-minify), you can configure it easily.
Just add a **.uglifyrc** file on your project root and add the following content to your file:

```
  {
      "output": {
        "comments": "/^\/*!/"
    }
  }
```

That will only preserve your license comments