# Keep license comments when using UglifyJS2 with gulp plugin

Tags: webpack, gulp, uglifyjs, gulp-uglify, uglifyjs2

In this project i am using [gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) version 3.0.1 and i want to preserve comments containing license texts in the output.

On the projects page it is stated that

```
Most of the minify options from the UglifyJS API are supported.
```

and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37542772/875020) shows how to pass [the minify options](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#minify-options) to the plugin.

In the [UglifyJS Readme](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#miscellaneous) it is stated that in order to preserve license texts

```
You can pass --comments to retain certain comments in the output. By default it will keep JSDoc-style comments that contain "@preserve", "@license" or "@cc_on" (conditional compilation for IE)
```

So i tried:

```
.pipe(uglify({
    mangle: true,
    output: {
        beautify: true,
        comments: "all"
    }
}))
```

But since even specifying `"all"` results in no license attribution comments, i assume that the minify option `comments` behaves differently then the commandline argument `--comments`.

I also tried the `preserveComments` found [here](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify/issues/215) but that just generates:

```
[13:37:42] GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
Caused by: DefaultsError: `preserveComments` is not a supported option
```

Is there a way to achieve what the [commandline argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25232340/875020) suggests via the `gulp-uglify` plugin? If not possible, can i use the [webpack plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin)?

There is [this workaround](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify/issues/82#issuecomment-82738907) by specifying [a regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25232340/875020) but i want to use the functionality directly from UglifyJS if possible. Besides, it doesnt keep the license headers like that either.

Comment: The [UglifyJS2 documentation clearly specifies the `comments` option under the output options with the same behavior](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#output-options). So it should work as you describe. Consider reporting this as a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. I noticed [the UglifyJS comments documentation](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS#keeping-copyright-notices-or-other-comments) suggested

> You can pass `--comments all` to keep all the comments, or a valid JavaScript regexp to keep only comments that match this regexp. For example `--comments /^!/` will keep comments like `/*! Copyright Notice */`.

So I tried "`comments: /^!/`":

```
.pipe(uglify({
    mangle: true,
    output: {
        beautify: true,
        comments: /^!/
    }
}))
```

I now see the copyright comments in the resulting uglified code.